# How to export search results from Splunk using Java or Javascript program.

Tags: javascript, java, splunk

We have a requirement to export large amount of results from Splunk. I heard Splunk provides Java SDKs that can be used to do this programatically rather manual export from Splunk. Since I am new to programming as well as Splunk , can someone provide an example or solution
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are different options to export data in Splunk.

- Splunk Web
- CLI
- REST
- SDK

The export method is entirely depends on the data volume and use case.

if you want to set up a higher-volume, scheduled data export, then the REST and SDK options are the best. The SDK supports both Java and Java Script.

The following is the documentation with examples,

http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.5.0/Search/ExportdatausingSDKs

http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.5.0/Search/ExportdatausingRESTAPI

Comment: I have a Splunk URL, how do i connect to it? i have seen examples for connect using host and port , But I don't know the host/port What I have is an splunk URL of our enterprise

Comment: Ok, If you want to export via REST APIs or SDK, you have to use your management port (default 8089) and not the Splunkweb port (default 8000).

For instance, the following could be your REST URI  if your enterprise is using the default port,

https://yourSplunk:8089/services/search/jobs/export

The same management port (default 8089) should be used to make a service connection from the code (when using SDK).

I would recommend you to check your enterprise and find the correct management port and URI.